# Golang use LIKE inside IF statement best practice

Tags: go

if i have many option to be filter in IF statement, can i use some function like this?

```
s1  := "lorem ipsum"
sum := 0

for _, v := range s1 {

        if string(v) like ("a","i","u","e","o") {
            sum+=1
        }

}
```

Comment: `if strings.ContainsRune("aiueo", v) { ...` [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/strings@go1.17.1#ContainsRune).

Comment: Or `if strings.ContainsAny(string(v), "aiueo") { ...` [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/strings@go1.17.1#ContainsAny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `switch` statement.

Switch supports multiple matches

```golang
switch string(v) {
    case "a","i","u","e","o":
       sum+=1 
}
```

Tried it in the playground - https://play.golang.org/p/QRYhEDA7EUZ

Comment: This is for an exact value match. The OP was asking for `like`.